# How do you get current renewal order id for woocommerce subscriptions?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce subscriptions with the custom function like below and can only get the parent order id from $subscription (from the order that initiated the subscription rather than getting each new order ID as renewals get triggered). Does anyone know how to get each new recurring order id?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_scheduled_subscription_payment', 'record_parent_referral_on_payment' );

function record_parent_referral_on_payment( $subscription ) {
....
```

Comment: are you use Stripe WC Gateway plugin ..? @Buster

Comment: No I'm using the FirstData Payeezy plugin with Woocommerce Subscriptions.